# What does it mean when Jacob declares that Issachar will be used for forced labor?

Tags: prophecy, jacob

Before Jacob dies, He says prophetic words about his sons.
(I understand that the fact that he condemns Reuben, Simeon and Levi because Reuben slept with one of Jacob's concubine, and Simeon and Levi killed the people of Shechem by trickery because Shechem had sexual relationship with Dinah.)

However, could someone please explain to me why Issachar will be used for  slave labor?

> Genesis 49:14-15, New American Standard Bible (NASB)
>
> “Issachar is [p]a strong donkey, Lying down between the
> [q]sheepfolds.  “When he saw that a resting place was good And that
> the land was pleasant, He bowed his shoulder to bear burdens, And
> became a slave at forced labor.

Answer (score 1):

Likely due in part to this question, virtually no commentaries actually interpret this as a curse, but rather twist it into some sort of blessing.

As an example, Gill follows many earlier Jewish commentaries in saying that Issachar would not be required to go out to war as the other tribes:

> and this tribe chose rather to pay more tribute than the rest, **that they might abide at home and attend the business of their fields**, when others were called to go forth to war.

Luzzatto quoting Dubno, notes how this played out, as per 1 Chronicles 12 (NIV):

> 23 These are the numbers of the men armed for battle who came to David
>   at Hebron to turn Saul’s kingdom over to him, as the Lord had said:
>
> 24 from Judah, carrying shield and spear—**6,800** armed for battle;
>
> 25 from Simeon, warriors ready for battle—**7,100**;
>
> 26 from Levi—**4,600**, 27 including Jehoiada, leader of the family of
>   Aaron, with **3,700** men, 28 and Zadok, a brave young warrior, with
>   22 officers from his family;
>
> 29 from Benjamin, Saul’s tribe—**3,000**, most of whom had remained
>   loyal to Saul’s house until then;
>
> 30 from Ephraim, brave warriors, famous in their own clans—**20,800**;
>
> 31 from half the tribe of Manasseh, designated by name to come and
>   make David king—**18,000**;
>
> **32 from Issachar, men who understood the times and knew what Israel should do—200 chiefs, with all their relatives under their command;**
>
> 33 from Zebulun, experienced soldiers prepared for battle with every
>   type of weapon, to help David with undivided loyalty—**50,000**;
>
> 34 from Naphtali—**1,000** officers, together with **37,000** men
>   carrying shields and spears;
>
> 35 from Dan, ready for battle—**28,600**;
>
> 36 from Asher, experienced soldiers prepared for battle—**40,000**;
>
> 37 and from east of the Jordan, from Reuben, Gad and the half-tribe of
>   Manasseh, armed with every type of weapon—**120,000**.